# How can I use sklearn's Binarizer in a Pipeline with muliple, custom thresholds?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Say I have a dataset with several features that I would like to binarize. Each feature has its own (manual) threshold. I have tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Binarizer

X = pd.DataFrame({"age": [20, 35, 67, 85, 98, 33, 28],
                  "BMI": [21.2, 24.2, 19.8, 28.1, 18.6, 31.3, 22.3]})
y = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0]

thresholds = {"age": 67, "BMI": 25}

pipe = Pipeline([('binarize', ColumnTransformer([("binarizer",
                                               Binarizer(threshold=list(thresholds.values())),
                                               list(thresholds.keys()))]))])

pipe.fit_transform(X, y)
```

However, the `Binarizer` class in `sklearn` does not support specifying multiple thresholds.

```
sklearn.utils._param_validation.InvalidParameterError: The 'threshold' parameter of Binarizer must be an instance of 'float'. Got [67, 25] instead
```

How can I binarize these variables in a pipeline using different thresholds for each variable?

Answer (score 1):

You could open a feature request Issue on sklearn's github (if one doesn't already exist for this, I didn't check).

In the meantime, you can just make more transformers in the `ColumnTransformer`:

```py
thresholds = {"age": 67, "BMI": 25}

ColumnTransformer([
    ("binarizer_age", Binarizer(threshold=thresholds["age"], ["age"]),
    ("binarizer_BMI", Binarizer(threshold=thresholds["BMI"], ["BMI"]),
])
```

or for lots, using a list comprehension:

```py
ColumnTransformer([
    (f"binarizer_{var}", Binarizer(threshold=thresh), [var])
    for var, thresh in thresholds.items()
])
```